# How to change the minimum collaps for bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I recently created a pretty long list in my bootstrap navbar, I'm wondering how I can change the setting for when my navbars to hide into the javascript button, check out the page with the problem at: http://www.twoog.org.

Thanks on beforehand.

Comment: can you explain what exactly is the problem? explain in DOM elements.

Comment: When you open the webpage in smaller resolutions, from around width:1400px ish, the navbar links pops to two lines, i would want to prevent that, by setting the navbar to collapse at 1400/1500px. I cant find this in the bootstrap.css file

Comment: I think it's controlled by the media queries in bootstrap-responsive.css: the screen resolutions there trigger the navbar change. That's if you have  bootstrap-responsive.css...

Comment: I have it yeah, i changed the resulutions there and it didnt work..

Comment: @media (min-width: 980px) {
  .nav-collapse.collapse {
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
} i changed this to 1400px, i didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that you used Images inside the menu. Use Text and Css Backgrounds.

Comment: Well is there no way i can change the max width before it collapses?

Comment: It will shrink the image, you dont wanna do that. Just Use text man.. and CSS background. its better coding.